# Need to read the sector 0 of a USB stick and make it removable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I need to read the sector 0 of a USB stick and make it removable. How can I do that? I am using C#, VS2008

Answer (score 2):

I can help you with the second part: safely removing it.

Here's [an article about a tool from Microsoft](http://ask-leo.com/is_there_a_way_to_safely_remove_hardware_from_a_batch_file.html) that will allow you to safely remove a flash drive from the command line. Using C# then, you can execute command line tools using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

**Update:**

You might investigate the windows API function [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) for reading raw disk sectors. You'll need use p/invoke to do this.

**Another Update:**

I did a search for you, and other people have had some success p/invoking to CreateFile using:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, System.UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, System.UInt32 dwShareMode, IntPtr pSecurityAttributes, System.UInt32 dwCreationDisposition, System.UInt32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Good Luck!